# Unable to download composer

Tags: software-installation, php, composer

I am getting this sort of error while downloading composer.

```
php composer-setup.php
All settings correct for using Composer
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/home/vasu/.composer/keys.dev.pub): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/vasu/composer-setup.php on line 468
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/home/vasu/.composer/keys.tags.pub): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/vasu/composer-setup.php on line 485
Downloading 1.2.0...
PHP Warning:  openssl_verify(): supplied key param cannot be coerced into a public key in /home/vasu/composer-setup.php on line 576
PHP Warning:  openssl_free_key() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/vasu/composer-setup.php on line 577
Signature mismatch, could not verify the phar file integrity
```

Answer (score 3):

### Easy way

Try the easy way first. The hard way was included in this answer because of the error messages mentioned in the comments.

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin  
sudo apt-get install curl
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php   
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

In Ubuntu 16.04 and later composer can be installed from the default Ubuntu repositories. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install composer
```

---

### Hard way

First check if `/usr/local/bin/` exists, and if not make the `/usr/local/bin/` directory.

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
```

If `/usr/local/bin/` already exists, the above command will do nothing except return this message:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/bin’: File exists
```

Run these commands:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/local/bin/  
cd /usr/local/bin/
ls # list the old composer file(s)
sudo rm <old-composer-files> # delete the old composer file(s)
sudo apt-get install curl
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php   
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Then if you type `composer` in the terminal it will be accessible globally in your system.

Comment: No I am still getting the same thing

Comment: I have composer in my usr/local/bin directory do I first need to remove that?

Comment: permission denied

Comment: every time I am trying to delete that it is saying permission denied