# Not able to install composer

Tags: software-installation, php, composer

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install- dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

When I run the above command in terminal I got this this response:

```
Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly.
Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:

The json extension is missing.
Install it or recompile php without --disable-json

The phar extension is missing.
Install it or recompile php without --disable-phar

The iconv OR mbstring extension is required and both are missing.
Install either of them or recompile php without --disable-iconv
```

Comment: Isn't `sudo apt install composer` working? Or you need exactly [composer.phar](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally)?

Comment: Why don't you try composer locally https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#locally

Comment: @SpasSpasov the .phar extension stands for **ph**p **ar**chive indicating how the file package is formatted, not what's in the archive.

Comment: @karel, I read about it and got it. Thank you for the direction.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 16.04 and later composer can be installed from the default Ubuntu repositories. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install composer
```

This command will also install the required PHP and JSON dependency packages along with it. Composer dependency manager for PHP helps you declare, manage and install dependencies of PHP projects, ensuring you have the right stack everywhere.

Comment: This works but does not get the latest version. How would one get the latest version of Composer (I'm on 18.04 bionic)?

Comment: 1. Change directories using `cd` to the directory where you want to install the latest version of Composer. 2. Run this command to download composer.phar: `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php` 3. If you want to use the new Composer that you installed globally instead of locally read the instructions in the 2nd section of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/820803/unable-to-download-composer/820805#820805).